# How to programmatically restart Microsoft Test Agent?

Tags: c#, batch-file, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

How can I programmatically restart the Microsoft Test Agent that would be equivalent to pressing the Restart button within the Test Agent Status window?  I'm willing to go about it any way possible.  Batch file, C# app, Powershell, etc.

[image]

Note:  Since I am running UI tests, I need to run the Test Agent as an "Interactive Process" and not a "Service"

Comment: Test agent is a windows service. You can control it using [ServiceController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Comment: I reviewed the running services on that box and none of them killed the qtagent process yet clicking the restart button above does. There doesn't seem to be an associated service in my configuration.

Comment: Try  `net stop vsttcontroller`.This will stops the test controller. The run  `net start vsttcontroller` to start it.

Comment: I restarted the controller (which is on a different box) and it does not kill the QTAgent process on my Agent boxes but restarting the agent via what I mentioned above does.

Comment: Why do you want to kill the agent? The agent just the software which shows the state of controller.

Comment: Great question. Because the agent process often hangs onto memory after tests runs and in some cases, causes crashes of the process and/or out of memory exceptions. There are various posts about it online.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because of QTAgent handles not properly closed after a test execution and succeeded in restarting the agent by doing the following in a batch file:

```
taskkill /f /im qtagentprocessui.exe  
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgentProcessUI.exe"
```

Restarting the agent services did not suffice to close the handles...

Hope this can help.

Comment: How did you configure the batch file to run?

Comment: I obviously could not do it from the agent so I had to use Windows Task Scheduler.  I am still experimenting with this....